# ExtJS - Display new tab when user click on row

Tags: javascript, extjs, ecmascript-6, extjs-grid

I have grid data in `ExtJS`. I've decided to insert a new tab whenever the user clicks on a specific row. The new tab contains information which has been transmitted from a row.

**Here is my code:**

```
columns: [
    {
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name',
        flex: 2,
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'searchtrigger',
                autoSearch: true
            }
        ]
    }, 
    {
        text: 'Price',
        dataIndex: 'price',
        flex: 1
    }
],
bbar: {
    xtype: 'pagingtoolbar',
    displayInfo: true,
    displayMsg: 'Displaying {0} to {1} of {2} &nbsp;records ',
    emptyMsg: "No records to display&nbsp;"
},
listeners: {
    select: function (tabPanel, newTab, oldTab, eOpts) {
        tabPanel.add({
            title: 'sometitle'
        });
    }
}
```

However, in the first step, I've got an error:

**Uncaught TypeError: tabPanel.add is not a function**

By the way, I have a couple of questions:

1- What is the best practice for transmitting data between two views in ExtJS?

2- Any suggestion to resolve the above issue?

EDITED: Here is the [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2k72):

Comment: Provide [fiddle](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor) for what you have tried so far.

Comment: I see that you're getting tabPanel as an argument of the select listener, do a console.log of arguments, and see if you're getting the correct type in arguments.

Comment: @RohitSharma I've added fiddle

Comment: Where is your `tabPanel` ? I think you didn't add full scenario in your code.

Comment: @RohitSharma I've used Ext.grid.Panel instead of tabPanel

Comment: Then, what do you mean by **I've decided to insert a new tab** ?

Comment: @RohitSharma, so you recommend changing 'Ext.grid.Panel' to 'tabPanel'?

Comment: May I ask you to put it as an answer?

Comment: Maybe you are asking about this type of result: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/2k73

Comment: @RohitSharma HELL YEAH! Thanks.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/177485/discussion-between-rohit-sharma-and-farzan-najipour).